# Why does iptables still block my samba?

Tags: networking, iptables, samba

I'm currently fighting with iptables and samba.

I read that samba needs ports 137-139 and 445 open on both tcp and udp.

Here is the relevant part of my iptables config

```
...
# forward valid incoming connections from lan to lan-services chain
-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.17.0/24 -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LANSERV
-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.17.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LANSERV
...
# samba
-A LANSERV -p tcp -m tcp --sport 137:139 --dport 137:139 -j ACCEPT
-A LANSERV -p udp -m udp --sport 137:139 --dport 137:139 -j ACCEPT
-A LANSERV -p tcp -m tcp --sport 445 --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A LANSERV -p udp -m udp --sport 445 --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
```

okay, 192.168.17.* is my local subnet which is connected to eth1.
What is wrong with these rules? Does samba need even more ports?

It is definetly the firewall since adding
`-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.17.0/24 -j ACCEPT` on top makes samba work.

edit: I'm trying to connect from a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "source port" means the port the remote machine sent the packet to your server from. Rarely, if ever, are client-to-server packets sent from the same remote port that they arrive on. This is due to the restriction in most OSes that dictate that normal users cannot open ports below a certain limit (in Linux it's any port below 1024).

Hence, the source port of the packets being directed to your machine are most likely coming from a random, high-numbered port on the remote host. In essence, the port number doesn't really matter and may as well not be specified.

The rule above expected packets to come from the *remote* port 137-139 and doesn't catch them if they don't. Remove the `--sport 137:139` and it should accept traffic to your port 137-139 from a remote machine's random high port.

Comment: omg thats really it? :/ well thank you. I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm able to test it.

Comment: it worked, accepted.